# Directly reading sensor data by paring Band 2 and PC (windows 8.1) still needs an emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, microsoft-band

I have to read sensor data from Band. I did search and became more confused. It seems there is a way to directly read data from Band by connecting with the desktop (windows 8.1) via Bluetooth. When I run a sample, it returns an error message like ‘deployment failure. No windows phone is detected’.

Is it possible to read sensor data from Band 2 this way?

1. Software environment: VS2015 community-Blank App (Universal windows);
2. Hardware environment: Band 2, desktop;
3. Pairing Band 2 with desktop via Bluetooth;

No windows phone and windows phone emulator get involved. Microsoft Health app is not used.
If yes, can I find sample code online?

Or it should be this way?

1. Software environment: VS2015 community-Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1), windows phone emulator, Hyper-V is required as well;
2. Hardware environment: Band 2, desktop, windows phone;
3. Pairing Band 2 with windows phone via Bluetooth;
4. Run the sample on the windows phone;

Both windows phone and windows phone emulator get involved.Microsoft Health app is not used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Band SDK in one of two ways:

1. Within a Windows Phone 8.1 or 10 (Universal) application running on a Windows Phone, where the Band is Bluetooth-paired to the phone.
2. Within a Windows Store 8.1 or 10 (Universal) application running on a Windows PC, where the Band is Bluetooth-paired to the PC.

The Band SDK is the same regardless of the hardware used, so any of the samples should be fine.

Note that you **cannot** use the Band SDK when your application is running in the Windows Phone emulator nor when the application is running in the Windows simulator.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply which means a lot of help for me! I appreciate that you share your wits us.
I still have questions that hope you can help.

Comment: For the option 1, do I need to register my Windows Phone 8.1 or 10 for development for the Windows Phone (here is one article: How to deploy and run an app for Windows Phone 8)? Then I can run the application directly on a Windows phone.

Comment: For the option 2, I tried before. I paired the Band with Windows PC (OS 8.1) via Bluetooth, then run a Windows Store 8.1 application to read data from Band 2 (no emulator). I end up getting first error message “There were deployment errors. Continue?”. If I click continue, I got “Bootstrapping ‘Device’ failed. Device cannot be found. Deployment failed b/c no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on”. Why I got those errors?

Thank you very much again Phil!

Comment: For Windows 8.1, yes, I believe you need to "developer unlock" the phone before deploying applications to it; this can be done with the Developer Registration utility that comes with Visual Studio.  For Windows 10, I believe "developer mode" can simply be enabled on the phone in Settings.  It's hard to say, but from the error message you provided it looks like Visual Studio was trying to deploy to a real phone rather than run as a Windows Store application.  Make sure that you've selected the deployment target appropriately.